# c# How to transform multiple structs into 1 bigger

Tags: c#, struct, interface

i have 6 structs for the player and also for the 5 bots. Everyone of them have some different variables and some that are equal to the other ones.I declare them like this

```
public struct Player
{
    public static int Chips;
    public static int Type;
    public static int Power;
    public static bool bot1Turn;
    public static bool bot1FoldTurn;
    public static AnchorStyles playerCardsAnchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom;
}
public struct Bot1
{
    public static int bot1Chips;
    public static int bot1Type;
    public static int bot1Power;
    public static bool bot1Turn;
    public static bool bot1FoldTurn;
    public static AnchorStyles bot1CardsAnchor = AnchorStyles.Left;
}
public struct Bot2
{
    public static int bot2Chips;
    public static int bot2Type;
    public static int bot2Power;
    public static bool bot2Turn;
    public static bool bot2FoldTurn;
    public static AnchorStyles bot2CardsAnchor = AnchorStyles.Right;
}
public struct Bot3
{
    public static int bot3Chips;
    public static int bot3Type;
    public static int bot3Power;
    public static bool bot3Turn;
    public static bool bot3FoldTurn;
    public static AnchorStyles bot3CardsAnchor = AnchorStyles.Top;
}
public struct Bot4
{
    public static int bot4Chips;
    public static int bot4Type;
    public static int bot4Power;
    public static bool bot4Turn;
    public static bool bot4FoldTurn;
    public static AnchorStyles bot4CardsAnchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right;
}
public struct Bot5
{
    public static int bot5Chips;
    public static int bot5Type;
    public static int bot5Power;
    public static bool bot5Turn;
    public static bool bot5FoldTurn;
    public static AnchorStyles bot5CardsAnchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left;
}
```

Later on i add the values in a static constructor :

```
static MainPoker()
{
    Player.Chips = 100000;
    Player.Power = 0;
    Player.Type = -1;
    Player.playerTurn = true;
    Player.playerFoldTurn = false;
}
```

Now should i keep all the 6 structs like this, or there's some other way to put them all together ? I'm looking for something like interface but it should also be able to hold static variables .. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Is there a specific reason your using structs instead of inherited classes?

Comment: Not really, structs were the first thing that came to my mind. If you can suggest me anything that will make the code look better and also function better...

Comment: You should almost never need to use structs in C# programming. The only place they are commonly used is when you are doing interop with native code or when they are used as read-only objects that do not have public properties or fields that are writeable. Switch them over to classes. Structs have subtle behaviors that will make your code look like it is bugged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Structs are value types, while classes are reference types. You almost certainly want to use classes for this type of thing.

You have many properties (which you have implemented as fields) in common between players and bots, and between the different "bot numbers". You decided to give all of those properties different names, which makes it difficult to simplify the code.

Your fields are declared static. I would suggest making them instance fields (or probably instance properties).

If you make those changes, you can use inheritance to put similar things in a common base type

```
public class Agent
{
    public int Chips;
    public int Type;
    public int Power;
    public bool Turn;
    public bool FoldTurn;
    public AnchorStyles CardsAnchor;
}

public class Player : Agent
{
    public Player() { CardsAnchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom; }
    // Anything that makes a player different here
}

public class Bot : Agent
{
    // Anything that makes a bot different here
    public Bot(AnchorStyles style)
    {
        CardsAnchor = style;
    }
}

Player player = new Player();
Bot bot1 = new Bot(AnchorStyles.Left);
Bot bot2 = new Bot(AnchorStyles.Right);
```

You an use properties in your code rather than fields. They will seem to behave similarly in code consuming the class, but properties afford more flexibility because they provide a layer between the value of something and how it is stored behind the scenes (for example, a property can be calculated based on the value of other properties or multiple backing fields). Using properties, you would instead write

```
public class Agent
{
    public int Chips { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public int Power { get; set; }
    public bool Turn { get; set; }
    public bool FoldTurn { get; set; }
    public AnchorStyles CardsAnchor  { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You may want to make more clear the diffrence between fields and properties (and perhaps make them properties in your example code)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Done

Comment: Can someone explain me why wertzui's answer is not better than this :?

Comment: @denis Neither is "better" they are just showing two diffrent ways of doing it. Because both `Bot` and `Player` share many traits using a base class they both pull from makes a lot of sense, but you don't "have" to do that either. In programming there is a principal called DRY (Don't Repeat yourself), if you have to write the same thing twice in two places you likely can combine it to a single place.

Comment: Yeah but i wonder isn't it better to create just 6 variables and work with them instead of creating so many classes

Comment: @denis: It is usually best to represent things in the real world (like a player or a bot) as a class, and represent things that describe that real-world object using properties. By doing that, you can use object oriented concepts like inheritance and polymorphism. If you just use variables, you will have many duplicate variables and messy code.

Comment: How can i later on pass those class variables are parameters for method with `ref/out` keyword ?

Comment: The best answer depends on exactly what you are trying to achieve. Suggest you open up a new question with code illustrating how you want to use ref/out. Often you would just pass the entire class instance but that's not always the best choice.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want structs, you want classes (except you really want structs, but then you would know it)
and you are mixing classes with instances of classes (objects).

Generate just one Player class and then create instances from it:

```
public class Player
{
    public int Chips { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public int Power { get; set; }
    public bool BotTurn { get; set; }
    public bool BotFoldTurn { get; set; }
    public AnchorStyles PlayerCardsAnchor { get; }

    public Player(AnchorStyles playerCardsAnchor, more parameters for properties)
    {
        PlayerCardsAnchor = playerCardsAnchor;
        // set other properties here
    }
}

MainPoker()
{
    var player = new Player(AnchorStyles.Bottom, more parameters);
    var bot1 = new Player(AnchorStyles.Left, more parameters);
    //more bots
}
```

If you need a static way to acces these, create a static class that holds references to these instances.

```
public static class PokerTable
{
    public static Player Player { get; }
    public static Player Bot1 { get; }
    // more bots

    static PokerTable()
    {
        Player = new Player(AnchorStyles.Bottom, more parameters);
        Bot1 = new Player(AnchorStyles.Left, more parameters);
        //more bots
    }
}
```

Then you can access the instances in a static way using

```
PokerTable.Player.Chips = 10;
```

Comment: Yea i was looking for something like this ! :)

Comment: From what I can see the player and bots are the same (just DTOs), so there is no need for a separate class.

Comment: What if you implement something only for the player, the bot shouldn't have? Might work for now, but consider heredity

Comment: The you start inheriting a base class or extracting an interface. You should not write code that you might need in the future. Write it, when you need it, otherwise you would end up with quite a lot of "dead" code on your project. Todays IDEs (like Visual Studio) make this process really easy.

Comment: And if i want to make the variables static i will just switch the constructor right ?

Comment: You do not want static variables. Then you would be back to where you came from. Maybe you need a static class that holds these instances (see my edit)

Comment: how can i pass these variables later on in methods with `ref/out` keyword ?

Comment: You do not want to do that. Either pass the Player/Bot object to a method or have a method that will take in a value and return a value without side effects. `int AddOneChip(int chips) { return chips + 1; } PokerTable.Player.Chips = AddOneChip(PokerTable.Player.Chips);`